# What is correct like pattern for number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like, sql-server-2017

I'm looking for correct pattern using like Operator.

My Code:

```
DECLARE @exp1 varchar(100) = '<<PointBalance , 8>>'
DECLARE @exp2 varchar(100) = '<<PointBalance , 985>>'    
IF (TRIM(REPLACE(@exp1, ' ', '')) LIKE '<<PointBalance,[0-9]>>')
    PRINT 'Matched'
```

As expected the if statement does not print 'Matched' for exp2.

Count of digits are not same. I need a pattern that validate are nDigit numbers.

Comment: could u edit question with ur desired result ? it is unclear for me.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I need to replace '<<PointBalance,[0-9]>>' with a pattern which print 'Matched' for both exp1 and exp2. did you get it?

Comment: for second @exp2  variable you will need to check it as `IF (trim(REPLACE(@exp2, ' ', '')) LIKE '<<PointBalance,[0-9][0-9][0-9]>>')` cause it length goes to 3 digits.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I know that. the problem is I do not know the number has how many digit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Like` patterns can't check for a variable length string of digits, but it can check a substring for any character that is *not* a digit:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample VarChar(32) );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values
  ( '<<PointBalance , 1>>' ), ( '<<PointBalance , 12>>' ), ( '<<PointBalance , 123>>' ),
  ( '<<PointBalance , 1234>>' ), ( '<<PointBalance , 1 3 5>>' ), ( '<<PointBalance , 1J3>>' );

with
  Step1 as (
    select Sample,
      -- Extract the substring starting after the comma and trim leading whitespace.
      LTrim( Substring( Sample, CharIndex( ',', Sample ) + 1, 32 ) ) as AfterComma
      from @Samples ),
  Step2 as (
    select Sample, AfterComma,
      -- Extract the substring prior to the first   '>'   and trim trailing whitespace.
      RTrim( Substring( AfterComma, 1, CharIndex( '>', AfterComma ) - 1 ) ) as TargetString
      from Step1 )
select *,
  -- Check the remaining string for any characters that are not digits.
  case when TargetString like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end as Numeric
  from Step2;
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance i would like to use of `substring()` with `patindex()` function to read the numeric values and compare the whole string

```
DECLARE @exp1 varchar(100) = '<<PointBalance , 811111>>'
DECLARE @exp2 varchar(100) = '<<PointBalance , 489>>'    
IF (trim(REPLACE(@exp2, ' ', '')) like '<<PointBalance,'+substring(@exp2, patindex('%[0-9]%', @exp2), len(replace(@exp2, ' ', '')) - patindex('%[0-9]%', replace(@exp2, ' ', ''))-1)+'>>')
PRINT 'Matched'
```

Comment: Is it a problem that `'<<PointBalance , 6 6 >>'` and `'<<PointBalance , 42y9 >>'` are "Matched"?